# How to interpolate Jenkins environment variables inside Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, environment-variables

I have a Jenkins pipeline,
One of the stages of the pipeline is to build the artifact from a java application code. 
The artifact always get the name hello-world-${BUILD_ID}.war using BUILD_ID jenkins environment variable for every build the name of the artifact will be changed.

Than, I have another stage in which I have to build a docker image for this artifact.
One of the lines of the Docker file is: 
`COPY hello-world-war-1.0.${BUILD_ID}.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/java-app.war`
In this line I have to copy the artifact to to the docker images.

For some reason, the mentioned interpolation doesn't work and when I run the pipeline I get the same error: 
`COPY failed: stat hello-world-war-1.0..war: no such file or directory`

Of course, when I hard code the number of the build id inside the Dockerfile, all work well.

Attached is a screenshot of the whole the Dockerfile.

Thanks in advance for any help !

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass your `BUILD_ID` as a [build argument](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg).

In your `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG BUILD_ID
```

In your `docker build` command:

```
docker build ... --build-arg BUILD_ID="${BUILD_ID}" ...
```

Environment variables like `${BUILD_ID}` are not passed to Dockerfile commands. This is voluntary, because `docker build` shoud be as reproducible as possible, without being dependent on build context. If you want a variable in the build process, it must be set explicitly.